# Lost a lot of weight ( around 13-15 Kg ) but cannot see any visible difference in my body shape. What's wrong?

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, bodyweight, ketogenic-diet

**Background & History**

I used to be a fit guy during my childhood till age 11-12 but after that I started gaining weight so much so that about 3 months ago I was 174.5 cm, around 83 Kg (age 18) my BMI was slightly over 25 at that time. Since the start of 2022 I started getting depressed over some of my personal issues and it was at peak during March & April after getting back to my senses I noticed that somehow my weight has been lost probably due to self inflicted startvation.

In August 2022 I started hitting gym, incorporated a bit of cardio as well and became concious about my diet ( initially just dumped all junk and packaged food even biscuits, gave up table sugar completely ).

Here's my body composition analysis ( In body Bioelectrical impedance analysis )

[image]

**Progress**

After one month of gym and restricted diet consisting completely homemade food I lost around 3 Kg of Fat. Here's another report after about 1 month but there's no visible body shape change in me.
[image]

Then for about half of September I continued my gym and diet but couldn't see much progress in weight loss so I switched my technique.

I started Ketogenic diet from 19th September 2022 and I'm still following the same, I haven't changed much in my gym routine in order to avoid muscle loss although my intensity has decreased a little in the gym due to my diet. I consume generally 1500-1600 kcal daily and was losing around 300 grams daily. It's been about two weeks and my current weight is about 69.5 Kg but still I haven't seen any visible difference in my shape. I haven't done my body analysis this month but I don't suspect any kind of muscle loss and my weight is also decreasing plus as per my reports you can see that my visceral fat level is also low.

**Question**

Then why don't I see any change in my body ? What am I missing ? What's the weight I lost if it's not subcutaneous fat ?

Feel free to ask more details if needed.

Comment: It should be noted the BIA is terrible at estimating body comp.

Comment: You lost 13kg and there's no visible change?? Are you just looking in the mirror or are you taking progress photos? It's much easier to see progress by taking regular pics (every 2 weeks should be enough)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov what else better option do I have that is readily available in my country India because DEXA is not readily available here ?

Comment: @Luciano well I to be honest I look in mirror but I can always pinch my skin on belly, arms, things etc and feel the subcutaneous fat lying beneath it .

Comment: I could also pinch my skin all throughout my fat loss... The key is to _measure how much_ you can pinch by using a caliper https://www.estimatebodyfat.com/caliper-calculator.html